# Removing ArcGIS Online icons in Mac menu bar?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online, vmware

I'm running ArcMap via VMware and each time I open it, an icon gets added to the menu bar.  They never go away when I quit the program, so I wind up with quite a little collection until I reboot.

[image]

Can I prevent these or close them?  They don't show in Force Quit.  Is each one constantly trying to connect to ArcGIS online?

Answer (score 1):

ArcMap 10.* by default adds and ArcGIS online connection for windows, adding a little icon to your taskbar. At 10.1 ArcMap would attempt this multiple times (default every 10sec) thus slowing down start-up.

There are 2 things to try:

1 Check and change how often and when ArcMap tried to make a connection.

- see if there is a little glob icon on your taskbar, if there is you can hover your mouse and get the current status of the connection. If not you will need to enable the connection. The steps are similar to disabling the connection except (below) you select "Show icon and notifications" instead of "Hide icon and notifications" from the drop down list of the dialog.
- right click the globe icon, select Properties
- change the connection option to say "Always check at the start of the session" if you want a connection or "Never" if you don't want a connection.

2 Disable the connection, and hence not display the icon. This means you cannot access ArcGIS content online.

In Windows 7 :

- Go to Show Hidden icons on your task bar (little up arrow) and Left click
- Select Customize Option

This should bring up the dialog : Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Notification Area Icons

- Find the ArcGIS Connection entry an select "Hide icon and notifications"
- OK.